# What is the safest transportation option in Cancun?

Tags: mexico, taxis, cancun

I am organizing a trip to Cancun with my family (Wife + 2 kids) to spend the Christmas vacations there, however, I am interested in acquiring a safe option to transport us, we will be staying 3 days in the Cancun Hotel Zone and other 2 days at the Riu Yucatan Hotel in Playa del Carmen.

I would like to know if private transportation is a viable option or if it is better to rent a car with a local agency, given that we're staying at two different hotels?

Comment: You say "eTransfers is [an] official and reliable provider." What do you mean by "official?" That word usually implies an operation by a government. Is eTransfers a government operation?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica it could also mean "official" as being registered and recognised by the airport (the airport has restrictions on taxi companies etc. allowed to pick up at the airport)

Comment: @JoelMartin Are you planning on driving around while at Cancun, making renting a car worth it?  Or are you just wanting to get to the Hotel Zone and back?  What is your reluctance to using an airport shuttle?

Comment: @Midavalo It might mean that...but the OP's use of "official transportation" makes me wonder.

Comment: Please provide details on what you want to do. Where is your hotel (or hotels), do you want to drive around, or just stay put in one place? If you just want to go the hotel zone, a shuttle is fine, but if you want to spend time in Tulum and a few other places, you would want a rental car.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I'm honestly not sure, but apparently, eTransfers is a company authorized by the airport to provide the service, according to what I've read.

Comment: @Midavalo We will be staying in an all-inclusive hotel, however, we would like to visit some sites such as archeological sites and parks like Xcaret and Xel-ha.

Comment: @Hilmar Yes, it is definitely something we want to do, we plan to dedicate at least 2 or 3 days to visit different places we have on our list, but I have read about some bad experiences with car rental agencies.

Comment: Watch out for "insurance included". This is usually the *minimum* level of cover required by law, and adequate insurance can make the rental significantly more expensive. Please see [Renting a car in Mexico](https://www.sfgate.com/mexico/mexicomix/article/Renting-a-car-in-Mexico-What-you-need-to-know-3787891.php).

Comment: Removed the links, these look like spam websites. The question itself is valid though and I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: I live in Mexico, and have never rented a car here, but I know people who have.  I would say all of them (that I can recall) have ended up having to pay for additional fees, insurance, other things they weren't aware of, when they picked up a car that they had booked and paid for online.  Both cheap rentals and big-name worldwide companies.  Personally I wouldn't book a rental or a private shuttle online - I'd wait until I got to the airport, or contact the hotel directly for their recommendation (or possible solution like hotel shuttle)

Comment: I'll add that if you are staying in an all inclusive hotel, that they will have likely services to visit all of the popular tourist locations.

Comment: @JonathanReez Sorry, I just put the websites as a reference to ask for an opinion, it was not my intention to spam. Apparently, they are established companies, but I'm a bit new on this.

Answer (score 4):

Transportation in Cancun can be a bit of a challenge. When you get out of customs, you will be accosted by aggressive car rental sales people and once you step out of the airport doors there are even more aggressive taxi agents.

Last time I was there (in June) we checked the rental places at the airport and they all had horror stories on Yelp (https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=carrental&find_loc=Canc%C3%BAn%2C+Quintana+Roo%2C+Mexico ) and other review sites. Insurance requirements in Mexico are complicated and most rental agencies (even big brand names) are trying to take advantage of their customers (to put it politely). Example: my credit card specifically offers CDW coverage and I have a written proof of this. I called one one brand name agency and submitted this document as they asked and the still would not confirm this. Their answer was "rent first, go to the local office and then the rental agent will decide whether they accept it or not", which is in my opinion an utterly unacceptable business practice.

We ended up renting with a local outfit called Easyway (no advertising intended) and were overall happy with the experience. They were upfront with the prices and didn't try to upsell or add-on more mystery fees.

Comment: I’ve heard the same horror stories about car rentals in Cabo but in the end had a hassle free experience with Avis: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151643/how-much-are-the-mandatory-undisclosed-fees-for-car-rentals-in-mexico. I somewhat suspect those stories are over exaggerated or caused by the tourists themselves, at least for Avis/Hertz.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a frequent traveler to Cancun and the Yucatan area. Private transportation is a very viable option - stick to pre-arranged rides or those arranged by your hotel/resort for the highest level of safety.

If you intend on exploring the area a bit, it may be worth it to rent a car. I personally always rent my own vehicle - I've had generally good experiences renting from Avis at CUN. Be sure to know basic phrases as gas stations are full-service and most attendants do not speak English. The drivers of the region are only slightly more aggressive than you'd find in a major American city, and traffic laws are generally observed by all.